# Starting a CSS animation every time a JavaScript function is called?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to get a CSS3 animation to animate every time a function is called.

My CSS code for the animation is in a class called 'enable' and it simply starts the animation.

My FUNCTIONS code is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("red").className = "enable";
    setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("red").className = "";
}, 1000);
```

That works properly when using the setTimeout function but when i change the entire FUNCTIONS code to say like this:

```
document.getElementById("red").className = "";
document.getElementById("red").className = "enable";
```

It only works **once**.

Why can't I remove the class and then add it immediately after.
Why doesn't my second code do the same thing as the first one?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: No, I'd prefer if we used pure JavaScript please!

Comment: Hmmm, alright, I guess I will make do with setTimeout for now. If anyone else has a solution to effectively achieve this please provide it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be helpful if included your html/css.

You have to use the setTimeout, otherwise the browser is not quick enough to pick up the change. Since javascript runs in a single thread, there is some breathing time needed for the browser to react to the change in class.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/brendonparker/75TfR

```
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
    #mydiv {
        -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
        transition: all ease 1s;
    }

    #mydiv.enabled {
        background: red;
    }
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="mydiv" >
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>

<!-- JS -->
<script>

    function animate(){
        var d = document.getElementById('mydiv');
        d.className = 'enabled';
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            d.className = '';
        }, 1000);
    }    

    animate();

</script>
```

Comment: The beginning portion of your answer is exactly the answer to my question! Thank you!